# Combining data from multiple tables issue Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

TABLE // FIELD
`Customer` // `Company`
`Stock` // `Description` 
`Manufact` // `Manu_Name` 
`Items` // `Quantity`, `total_price`

I am using Oracle 11g Application Express.  I need to display a list of each stock ordered for EACH CUSTOMER.  I need to display the Manufacturer, quantity ordered, and total price paid.

When I run this query within my SQL*PLUS command prompt, it endlessly displays results from the tables mentioned until I force-quit (ctrl+c) the application.  This is incredibly frustrating - I've tried joining tables, using the EXISTS clause, I just don't know what the hell to do.  Any insight would be wonderful - not looking for someone to simply solve this for me, more-so just guide me.

`SELECT c.company, s.description, m.manu_name, i.quantity, i.total_price
FROM db1.customer c JOIN db1.orders o USING (customer_num), db1.stock s, db1.manufact m, db1.items i
WHERE o.order_num = i.order_num;`

This causes a never-ending display of what seems like the same results, over, and over, and over.
Essentially, I need to display the required information for EACH ORDER of stock.  However, I don't need the `order_num` in my output display of columns, so I thought I needed to use the `order_num` (in `db1.orders o` & `db1.items i`) to essentially tell Oracle, "For each order_num (an order can't exist without an order_num), display (results)...

I am incredibly lost - I've tried outer joins, I've tried using an EXIST operator, I am just stumped and I feel like it's something easy that I'm overlooking.

---

EDIT:  So, it seems I finally found it, after an enormous amount of pondering.

This is how I did it, in case anyone else runs into this issue:

`SELECT c.company, s.description, m.manu_name, i.quantity, i.total_price
FROM db1.customer c JOIN db1.orders o USING (customer_num)
JOIN db1.items i USING (order_num)
JOIN db1.stock USING (stock_num)
JOIN db1.manufact m ON m.manu_code = s.manu_code
ORDER BY c.company, s.description;`

If you `JOIN db1.manufact m USING (manu_code)`, you get an `ambiguously defined column` error from Oracle - this is because I already joined the other tables and that column was in one of them (It was the `db1.stock` table).  You can still join them, but you have to use JOIN ON instead.

This displayed the results I needed.  Thanks anyways, and cheers if this helped anybody out!

Comment: What tables is manu_code in? If three then you can still join manufact USING manu_code. But there must be only one manu_code column in what it is being joined to. That is the result of prior joins. So if there is a manu_code in two of the preceding tables then when you join the second one you need to add manu_code to that USING also. Also then you cannot qualify manu_name when you seect it. Because you cannot qualify a column used in USING.  See [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fc94c/2) where customer, items & manufact all have manid.

Answer (score 1):

You've only provided two joins (one `USING` and one in the `WHERE`) between 5 tables - in this case, you will get the cartesian product of all other rows in all other tables, hence the large number of rows.

(*Edit, by implication you need to join all tables together, whether by `USING` or `JOIN`*)

In order to use the `USING` join sugar, the same column must be present on the immediate lhs and rhs tables. <del>For multiple joins, into a hierarchy, you may need to nest the `USINGs` like so:
   SELECT c.company, s.description, m.manu_name, i.quantity, i.total_price
   FROM customer c
   JOIN orders o 
        JOIN stock s
             JOIN items i 
                   JOIN manufact m USING(manid)
             USING(itemid)
       USING (stockid)
   USING (customer_num);</del>

There `where` join isn't needed since we already have the `USING` join

I've assumed some columns and relationships between your table in [this fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91ef6/5):

You can also drop the `USING` and use explicit `JOIN` syntax, which will allow you to avoid the nesting (this is also more portable across the ANSI world):

```
SELECT c.company, s.description, m.manu_name, i.quantity, i.total_price
FROM customer c
  INNER JOIN orders o on c.customer_num = o.customer_num
  INNER JOIN stock s on o.stockid = s.stockid
  INNER JOIN items i on i.itemid = s.itemid
  INNER JOIN manufact m on m.manid = i.manid;
```

**Edit**
As OP has demonstrated, no requirement to nest the `USING` joins, provided that the join ordering is sensible, and provided that the FK JOIN column isn't duplicated across multiple tables.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/91ef6/9

Comment: There is no problem with any number of tables having a given JOIN USING column. But each time it is in both sides of a JOIN it must be in the USING. (See my comment on the question.) (Thanks for the fiddle.) PS: FKs are irrelevant to joining. When present a FK just means there will only be one referenced row matching each referencing row.